# Capitalization of framework names under Snow Leopard

Tags: opengl, frameworks, osx-snow-leopard

One user running Snow Leopard wasn't able to compile my code. After an hour I finally found the real reason. The compiler option to include the OpenGL framework was `-framework OPENGL`. After changing it to `-framework OpenGL` it worked. It also seems to work under earlier versions of MacOS X.

How are capitalizations handled here? Can I just use `-framework OpenGL` and be safe or is there a case where it has to be `-framework OPENGL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably just depends on whether you are using a case-sensitive file system such as those commonly found on Linux (as opposed to a case-preserving file system, such as HFS+, as commonly used on OS X). If you always use the correct capitalisation (i.e. matching the framework name on disk) then you should be OK. Since in this case it's `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework` then it should be `-framework OpenGL` in your build options.